# How can I parse xml in xslt variable

Tags: xslt

I want to get the value from variable $TYPE by key=20AC. 
But all under variable tag are genrate by database at run time.

```
<xsl:variable name="TYPE" >
      <xsl:value-of select="db:getTyeCode()"/>
           <!-- Data will generate by about customize function -->
           <data>
              <entry key="20AC">20A0</entry> 
              <entry key="22AC">22A0</entry>
           </data>
           <!-- generate by function-->
</xsl:variable>
```

Do know how to get the value in value-of select.

```
<xsl:value-of select=""/>
```

Comment: How do you call database at run time from xslt? How do you obtain result of that query? What version of xslt do you use?

Comment: Hi I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: And I have call a function and get value from db.
xmlns:db="java://customfunction.db.query"
 
<xsl:variable name="TYPE" >
     <xsl:value-of select="db:getTyeCode()"/>
</xsl:variable>